# Rules of html and css ZOOM-IN, ZOOM-OUT.Prevent the collapse

Tags: html, css

hy...I'm building some website and when I zoom-in or zoom-out(especially when I zoom-out) my website collapse. Does anyone know some tutorial or notes about these rule where they explain that? If you do please paste a link =)

thank you, and sory for my English

Greetings, from Slovenia!

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` saves it from collapsing, although there would be still some irregularity upon zooming; when zooming out, things tend to the right-hand side of the screen.